# Python - strings and numbers in array, want to sum all numerical values in row, and append value to end of row

Tags: python, arrays, csv

Beginner here. I just started trying to learn Python yesterday as sort of a summer project.

I have a CSV that I stored as an array. Its a little bigger than this example but if you can show me how to do it on this one, I can probably extrapolate it.

```
Bob  |  10  |  15  |  20
Jim  |  20  |  23  |  32
Sue  |  03  |  21  |  09
```

I'd like to add a column to the end of the table that sums the values, obviously ignoring the strings in the first column. So to get something like this:

```
Bob  |  10  |  15  |  20  |  45
Jim  |  20  |  23  |  32  |  75
Sue  |  03  |  21  |  09  |  33
```

So far I have code something like this

```
import numpy
import csv
vlhpcsv = open('file.csv')
importeddata = csv.reader(vlhpcsv)

from numpy import genfromtxt
genfromtxt_vlhp = genfromtxt('file.csv',delimiter=',', skip_header=1, dtype=None, usecols=(9,10,11,19,21,22))

relevant_columns = numpy.array(genfromtxt_vlhp)

print(relevant_columns)
```

This does what I expect, and shows me a pared-down version of the original CSV, with just the data I care about. Any attempt to try to sum and append afterward though, is met with a "cannot perform reduce with flexible type" error. I know this is because of the strings in the first column; I just don't know what to do about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would use [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import  pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

df["tot"] = df.sum(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Input:

```
name,v1,v2,v3
Bob,10,15,20
Jim,20,23,32
Sue,03,21,09
```

Output:

```
 name  v1  v2  v3  tot
0  Bob  10  15  20   45
1  Jim  20  23  32   75
2  Sue   3  21   9   33
```

To save the data to csv you just need [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) using `header=False` if you don't want a header and with `index=False`  to output without row names/indexes:

```
df.to_csv("test2.csv", index=False,header=False)
```

Output:

```
Bob,10,15,25
Jim,20,23,43
Sue,3,21,24
```

You can specify the columns to use with `usecols` the same way, using `axis=1` will sum the rows and any non numeric cols data will be ignored.

Comment: When I try to run this code, I get the error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_csv'"

Comment: @jbf,  what did you call your script?

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're a beginner, I'm going to ask if you have an explicit reason to be using numpy. What you're doing in this specific scope doesn't really call for it, so it might be easier for you to take advantage of Python's built-in csv handling:

```
import csv

output_rows = []

# Open the input file with Python's built-in open()
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    # Create a Reader object pointing to the csv file
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    # Use the Reader to loop through each row in the csv
    for row in reader:
        sum = 0
        # Each row is given to us a list; loop through that list
        # to gather up all the numbers and sum them
        # Note the [1:] says "start at position 1 (the second element)
        # and continue to the end of the list"
        for number in row[1:]:
            sum += float(number)
        # We'll give output_rows a new row that's the original
        # row + the computed sum at the end
        output_rows.append(row + [sum])

# Open the output file, passing 'w' to note it's in write mode
with open('output.csv', 'w') as outputfile:
     # Make a csv Writer object with the file
     writer = csv.writer(outputfile, delimited=',')
     for row in output_rows:
         # Write each row to the file using writerow(), which takes
         # a list and prints it to the file, using the specified delimiter
         # to separate each entry
         writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Maybe add some in-line comments for the beginners reading this answer.

Comment: as for why i'm using numpy - everything i found seemed to imply that it was the best for manipulating arrays, which i'll be doing a lot of once i get this script up and running. and like i said, i'm pretty much doing this as a way to learn python. i'm an engineering student so i think it would be useful.

Comment: yeah, like he said above, i'm having a bit of trouble following all the logic in this code, but i think i mostly understand it. however, i tried to implement it into my program and it gives me the error "ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'"11"'" - which is strange to me because "11" is not the first value in the list, it's the second one. why does python not have trouble interpreting the first value as float but sees 11 as a string?

Comment: In Python, we have the really wonderful List object which is much more flexible than standard arrays. Arrays are still useful for certain things, but Lists are probably what you want to use. For the error you're getting, I would check your input file to make sure nothing weird is going on -- that 'b' at the start of the string says that Python's reading that entry as pure binary, which is unusual.

Comment: Comments appended, also, so hopefully the code is more helpful now! Sometimes it can be hard to tell what's obtuse, so I'm sorry for the confusion.